# get the FragmentManager from within a Fragment (support.v4)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Be aware, I am using the `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`. I have searched all over the internet, I have found many similar questions, but they are all referring to `android.app.FragmentManager` and none of the solutions work with support.v4 FragmentManager.

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
```

I am using Fragments instead of Activities for navigation purposes. Inside my MainActivity I have a NavigationDrawer which is used to select a Fragment to be displayed using the following method:

```
public boolean onNavigationSelected(MenuItem item) {

    FragmentManager fragManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.fragment_one) {
        fragManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, new FragmentOne()).commit()
    }
    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.fragment_two) {
        fragManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, new FragmentTwo()).commit()
    }

}
```

This works fine when a user navigates using the NavigationDrawer, but there are Buttons inside the Fragment which are used for navigation too, however the `getSupportFragmentManager()` method cannot be called from within a Fragment.

FragmentOne:

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for the Fragment
        fragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one_layout, container, false);

        // Do some stuff to the fragment before returning it

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                // This does not work
------------>   FragmentManager fragManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, new FragmentTwo()).commit();
            }
        });

        return fragment;
    }
}
```

Comment: try getActivity().getSupp...

Comment: I've tried that, along with `getContext().getSupp...` I get a cannot resolve method error.

Answer (score 1):

The Activities' `getSupportFragmentManager()` is the Fragment's `getFragmentManager()`.

The only reason that the Activity's method is named `getSupportFragmentManager()` is to avoid conflicting with the framework `getFragmentManager()` method. There is no such requirement in the Fragment class.

Comment: using `getFragmentManager()` I get the following error:

Incompatible types.
Required: android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager
Found: android.app.FragmentManager

Comment: You still have to use `getSupportFragmentManager()` in the Activity. It is in the Fragment that you use `getFragmentManager`. Your error message doesn't come through in comments - try adding it to your question.

Comment: I pressed enter to go to next line, forgot to hold shift.
I've edited previous comment with error message.

Comment: That's the error you get when you try to use `getFragmentManager()` in the Activity. That's not what you want to use.

Comment: Be sure that you are actually using the support version of Fragments. It could be the case that your are mixing SupportActivity with native Fragments.

Comment: I am still using `getSupportFragmentManager()` in the Activity. I am getting the error inside the Fragment.

Comment: 100% sure I am using support Fragments.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to use `getActivity().getFragmentManager()`? It is just `getFragmentManager()` in the Fragment.

Comment: Atmost you can have `getChildSupportFragmentManager()` within the fragments...anyway, you can solve your `button click-fragment transaction` using an interface !! @EdwinOwen